# Golf conversions, combining multiple array formulas to keep a "clean sheet"

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I run a weekly custom golf pool and I have a complex problem.  I want to use multiple array formulas so I don't have to change multiple formulas per week based on the varying number of participants.

I have three sheets; Leaderboard, Picks and Live Scoring.  I pull data from an API for Live Scoring. Picks is an array from 'Form Responses 1'(not shown) from a google form.  I need help creating a dynamic leaderboard.

In the current scenario I have used a couple of array formulas to formulate the Leaderboard sheet. Ultimately I would like to "clean up the look" by getting rid of columns B through G and just leaving column A and H. I think I just need to make one MASSIVE formula.

How it works- each participant selects six golfers.  We use the best four scores. I need this to be reflected in column H on the Leaderboard sheet. To complicate matters, I likely need to convert all "E" to "0" and all "CUT" to "+10".

I've created this mock sheet to simulate some of the problems that I have. I figured the first step is to replace the text (E and CUT) with the corresponding values.  B10:G12 on Leaderboard shows I know how to convert the "E" to "0" but for some reason when I add that into the arrayformula B2:G5, it doesn't allow the formula in H to work. Essentially it's a setback.

I know there's a lot here but any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm only a few months into learning google sheets and scripts so I still have a long ways to go :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DY9VUzvGYAGqYAnZ2KDC5YMLQ3eo24EgGW_RcRQ3MiQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You might want to try Webapps StackExchange. StackOverflow is for programming/software engineering, but the StackExchange network has many sites for other categories of questions.